# Code-First ASP.NET MVC5 data update not reflecting immediately

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

I am working on a project which is codefirst MVC5 project. I have a few tables along with Identity2. There are some tables when i am making changes in it, they are not reflecting immediately. During development if i stop the debugging and restart only then the changes are appearing in front, However the changes are happening immediately in DB.

Example:

Lets say i have a system settings table where i am updating the column in a row to false. It doesn't take affect until i stop n start debugging again. Same happens only the production server as well. What's funny is it doesn't do the same for all the tables/columns. Just a few of them, Like AspNetUsers table takes changes immediately.

Can anyone explain what could be wrong with this?

Comment: How do you know that changes "are not reflecting immediately"? Do you check the value in your database or are you evaluating its effects somewhere, e.g. in the front-end? Can you post some code to show what's happening?

Comment: are you using any kind of caching? or if you are checking this through the browser then try clearing the browser cache